# File Visiblity in live linux version

Tags: live-cd, livedvd, live-environment

Q. How can we make file visible, which an user have created earlier while working with Live -Linux version. The file should be visible when system restarts.

Answer (score 0):

All files created during an Ubuntu live session must be stored **outside** of this live session if we want to keep them.

You should therefore educate you users how to mount an existing internal or external drive, or an USB stick for storing their data. This can even be an additional partition in the USB drive you had booted the live system from but it can't be the virtual drive that was created by the live session.

If that drive was formatted with a Linux filesystem you need to take care of file permissions. Storing files on a Windows filesystem (e.g. NTFS, FAT32) will not have permission issues.